# Cypress truncates the URL after login

Tags: cypress

I have a simple login test in cypress (5.6.0, Windows 10). The application I am testing is written in PHP/MySQL. When I run the test in Cypress I get a 404 page not found error following the login.
This does not happen manually or with webdriver, just with Cypress.
Here is the script (which you can try)

```
describe('Admin Login', () => {
Cypress.config('baseUrl','https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/webdriver2')

it.only('Successful Login', () => {
    cy.visit ('/')
    cy.get('div#right-column > h1').contains('Web Testing Index Page V2 Sprint2')
    cy.contains('Login').click()
    cy.get('body').contains('User is not Logged in').should('exist')
    cy.get('#username').clear()
    cy.get('#username').type('edgewords')
    cy.get('#password').clear()
    cy.get('#password').type('edgewords123')
    cy.contains('Submit').click()
    //error 404 occurs here
    //cy.visit ('/sdocs/add_record.php') //Had to add this as Cypress changes the URL from the form submit for some reason!
    cy.get('body').contains('User is Logged in').should('exist')
    //Logout
    cy.contains('Log Out').click()
    //Handle the confirmation Alert
    cy.on('window:confirm',(str)=>{
        expect(str).to.equal('Do You Really want to Exit the Secure site! Press ok to Continue ')
    })
    cy.get('body').contains('User was Logged in').should('exist')
});
```

And when I run with Chrome or Firefox, I get this in the log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xpG.jpg)

and in the Test Runner, the URL has been truncated:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fembf.jpg)

The URL should be https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/webdriver2/sdocs/add_record.php,
but cypress changes it to https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/sdocs/add_record.php

**webdriver2** is just a physical folder on the web server where this app/site is stored.
I see that someone else had a similar issue, but there are no replies on his question. Could anyone help? Thanks

Since the above post, I have now looked at the login function in the application itself.

```
else {
                // document.write(response);
                //location.replace("../sdocs/add_record.php");
                
                //Had to change the line below as in Cypress, it is not moving back to the previous directory
                //so have made it an absolute url instead
                //window.location.href = "../sdocs/add_record.php";
                window.location.href = "https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/webdriver2/sdocs/add_record.php";
                return false;
                }
```

The relative url path above should just go back to the parent directory (webdriver2) which it does if you use the site manually.
However, I have had to fix this as a fully qualified url to make it work in cypress.
So I have a workaround, but why does cypress handle it differently?

Comment: Do you have a cypress config file alongside your tests? I think defining it within the test file would take precedence, but if it's there then it might be causing Cypress some confusion.

Comment: I am using baseURL in the cypress.config file, but have now removed that, and removed the Cypress.config statement, and just use a simple cy.visit with full URL, but problem still persists. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Also, just a note that I have tried http as well as https, and that problem still there

Comment: Where you are originally doing the location.replace action, if you change the double dot to a single dot, does it solve the problem in Cypress?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but good idea. when I try ./ then on the website (manually), the URL is not found as I get https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/webdriver2/sdocs/sdocs/add_record.php
And in Cypress, I end up with not found with this URL - http://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/__/sdocs/add_record.php
I have also tried using ./../  at the start of the location.replace, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it work in Cypress, though?

Comment: No. It still misses out the webdriver2 part of the URL. Definitely a cypress thing, as all ok manually in any browser, and fine in webdriver, just cypress for some reaaon

Comment: Would it be worth opening a ticket on Cypress' GitHub page?